# What exactly is a wall void?

Tags: walls, pest-control, termite

A [termite insecticide (fipronil)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B7B389G) is not to be used indoors, except in wall voids.  If a hole was drilled in a baseboard or wall and the the foam was delivered through the wall, is this considered delivery to a wall void?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the void is the space inside the wall. It could be between joists in a wood wall or in the channels inside concrete blocks. It basically just means empty spaces in a wall.